# Android Action Bar tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to build the ActionBar Tab with tabs bottom. Can some one please throw light on how to have the Android3+ version's ActionBar tabs at bottom?

Comment: Millions of users get used to the ActionBar and they get used to the ActionBar being on the TOP, and now you want to put it on the bottom. Why? It's like playing a mean trick on people. Betcha can't find the ActionBar now!!! Bwhwhahahah

Answer (score 4):

> Can some one please throw light on how to have the Android3+ version's ActionBar tabs at bottom?

AFAIK, tabs are always at the top, even with a split action bar.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the ActionBar is always at the top.

You might be thinking about [split action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar) though. This is used for phones that have smaller screens so they can take some additional items.